# How to ignore multiple files with `ag` The Silver Searcher

Tags: regular-expression, patterns, ack, ag

There is an option `--ignore` which allows specifying files to ignore. At the moment I only managed to ignore multiple files by doing `--ignore file1 --ignore file2.......`

Trying to use `--ignore "*assets*|*scripts*"` does nothing. So is there a catch I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use brace expansion e.g.

```
ag pattern --ignore={'*assets*','*scripts*'}  path_to_search
```

or, as [Glenn suggests here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36165680), process substitution:

```
ag pattern -p <(printf "*%s*\n" assets scripts) path_to_search
```

Comment: Completely forgot about expansion feature. Still wondering why man says `--ignore PATTERN`. Naturally would expect `PATTERN` to be regex...

Comment: @T.Chmelevskij - not really, when it comes to file names, PATTERN almost always means SHELL PATTERN...

Answer (score 3):

format is **--ignore pattern_to_exclude**

```
➜  proj git:(develop) ✗ ag User -l  | wc
     82      82    2951
➜  proj git:(develop) ✗ ag User -l --ignore 'tests*' | wc
     65      65    2348
```

**proof**

```
➜  exp tree                                              
.
├── good.py
├── migrations.py
├── test2.py
├── test_another.py
└── tests.py

➜  for i in *.py; do echo "User" > $i; done 
➜  exp ag -l --ignore 'test*' --ignore 'migrations*' User
good.py
```

so only one file **good.py** has been returned, all others got filtered due to pattern

Comment: You are only ignoring filenames with the exact name of  `tests` here. The question was how to ignore multiple patterns.

Comment: you can submit another --ignore, like **ag User -l --ignore tests --ignore migrations**

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, but please read the whole question when answering. _At the moment I only managed to ignore multiple files by doing --ignore file1 --ignore file2......._ question was on how to shorthand that. Shell expansion is the best solution seen so far. So your own solution could be shortened to `ag -l --ignore={'test*','migrations*'} User`

Comment: for some reason that didn't work for me (ag 0.33 + zsh) that's the reason I have added additional answer what worked for me. I read your question before answering.

Comment: Brace expansion is shell feature, not `ag`. Also I'm using `zsh` myself. Are you sure you don't have space somewhere in `--ignore={'test*','migrations*'}`? You can simply try `echo --ignore={'test*','migrations*'}` and it should print out those things.

Comment: I'll check one more time :)

Answer (score 2):

You could add

```
*assets*
*scripts*
```

to your `.gitignore` or `.ignore` file.

From the readme:

```
It ignores file patterns from your .gitignore and .hgignore.
If there are files in your source repo you don't want to search, 
just add their patterns to a .ignore file.
```

Comment: I am aware of `.ignore` files. But changing file every time just to exclude directory for one search is not really convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Coming a bit late on this thread.

In `ag`, `--ignore` doesn't support regular expression.
So if you want to ignore all files with say ".json" extension, you need to use `--ignore='*.json'` rather than that `--ignore='.*.json'`

If you want to ignore multiple file extensions, you can do the following:
`ag  --ignore='*.yaml' --ignore='*.json'`

The above will ignore files with `yaml` and `json` extensions.